# How to increase the horizontal space between buttons on jquery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uibutton, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using [jquery ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and I wanted to see if there was any way to include the horizontal space in between buttons on the dialog?  I Can't see anything in the documentation or from googling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The best way is adding styling to your buttons.** Specifically, `margin-right`, or `margin-left` values:

```
buttons: [
    { text: "Save", click: function () { alert("save"); }, style:"margin-right:40px;" },
    { text: "Cancel", click: function () { alert("close"); ;}, style:"margin-left:0px;" }
]
```

feel free to play with this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/zVCYa/)**.

The more you increase either `margin-left` or `margin-right`, the more separated the buttons will be horizontally.

alternatively, you can also create classesbut in this case, id lean toward in-line styling because this is such a localized use.

Answer (score 3):

Very simply use the class markup that jQuery UI offers you. No need to tweak anything with javascript, just use plain CSS :

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset button:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

(`:Not` selector doesn't work in IE6/7, but with all other browsers it works fine)

Answer (score 2):

Depends..

1. Solution 1 , 2: as *Dave A* and *BabyAzerty* stated above
2. Solution 3: If it is only one modal and same across everything

   **your.css**

   ```
   .ui-button {
       margin-left: 10px !important;
   }
   ```
3. Solution 4: if you have got more modals

   **javascript**

   // call your dialog with dialogClass option and then you can play with anything :)
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass: "my-style" });

   **your.css**

   .my-style .ui-button { margin-left: 10px !important; }